# Magento 2 hide links in my account page conditionally

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Hi guys i am trying to hide few links under the customer navigation panel conditionally.

i have these setup done.

**customer_account.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-create-agent-createagent">
            <arguments>
               <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">my/agent/createagent</argument>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Create Agent</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-create-agent-viewagent">
            <arguments>
               <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">my/agent/viewagent</argument>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">View Agent</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**current.php**

```
<?php

namespace [vendorname]\[module]\Block\Agent;
// namespace Namespace\Module\Block\View\Element\Html\Link;

//use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class Current extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current{

protected $_customerSession;
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $CustomerSession,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_defaultPath = $defaultPath;
    $this->_customerSession = $CustomerSession;
}


public function toHtml(){

      if($this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getYourAttribute()){
           return parent::toHtml();
      }
      return '';
   }  
}
```

I wanted to hide the two links named "Agent Create" and "Agent View" id the user is not of a particular group.

This is an implementaion i was trying , but i didnt get any result.
Please help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using an observer.

Create following files in your custom module.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
        <observer name="removeblock" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Removeblock" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Removeblock.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Removeblock implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getLayout();

        $your_condition = 1; // write your conditional logic here

        if($your_condition == 1){
            $layout->unsetElement('your_block_name');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface;

class BlockName extends Current
{

    /**
     * BlockName constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath
        ) 
        {
        parent::__construct($context, $defaultPath, []);
    }

    public function manageLink()
    {
        if (condition) {
            $this->getLayout()->unsetElement('blockname');
        }
    }
}
```

**create file : app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Blockname" name="blockname">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">frontname/controller/action</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">name of label</argument>
                </arguments>
                <action method="manageLink"></action>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I think I prefer this solution as only fires when creating that link. Works a treat.